# Segmentation fault while accessing GPIO

Tags: linux, embedded, gpio

first of all sorry for asking this, I've already read some similar problems here but no topic had my answer. And also I'm total newb in programing embedded linux and this is my first time using linux so be polite please :)

So, my problem is: I'm trying to do some basic application for embedded linux system (AT91SAM9260 mcu) with GPIOs - blinking led or some buttons. But when I try to access GPIOs via their address (for example 0xE002C00C), program shows "Segmentation fault". What I found so far that it means linux wont let me to use memory which I'm trying to access. Many people suggests that I should write my own driver or whatever, but as I said I'm absolute newbie in this and I have no idea what should I do. Can someone help me with this? step-by-step instructions would be great.

Thanks in advance, muliku.

Comment: you need to use mmap() or write a driver to use physical addressing.

Comment: *"But when I try to access GPIOs via their address (for example xE002C00C)"* -- As as longtime user of the AT91SAM9260 SoC, that (physical) address doesn't even look valid for **any** system peripheral register.

Comment: @dwelch *"write a driver to use physical addressing"* -- A device driver would have to ioremap() the physical address, which is essentially the equivalent of mmap().  The CPU cannot access memory using physical addresses while the MMU is enabled.

Comment: @sawdust, right, understood, the OP already knew that drivers could (in some way) access physical addresses, was simply pointing out mmap() for application space.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you are running Embedded Linux it would also be helpful to give information like kernel version, which BSP provided by whom or any build system like Openembedded or buildroot. If you are running Linux, the standard way of accessing GPIO's on Linux is from /sys/class/gpio. See [GPIO sysfs](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt). Check if the kernel you use has already exported them.

As to your segmentation fault, on a monolithic kernel like Linux there is a separation of user space and kernel space. One cannot access any address directly. All addresses are memory mapped and there is a translation between virtual address and physical address.

If you have a recent kernel or your vendor Atmel or otherwise provided a properly configured kernel/BSP you should be able to access GPIO's through sysfs since a GPIO driver and any necessary support would be included.